# Find integral exact formula

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let when $0 \leq x < 1$ $$f(x) = x$$  and when $ 1 \leq x \leq 4$ $$\lfloor \sin x \rfloor + 1$$

a. Find the exact formula for the function $F(x) = \int_\limits{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ in $[0,4]$.

b. show that $f$ has primitive function in $[0, 1.5]$ and find the primitive $G(x)$ of $f$ in $[0, 1.5]$ and that $G(1) = 0$

About (a) I wasn't really sure what does it mean the "exact formula".
and in (b) I know that it does have a primitive function since it's a continuous function in $[0, 1.5]$ but how can I calculate it ?